# How to filter a list by appended change date range of a specific column

Tags: list-view, filter

What is the best solution to create a view having a filter on a column that has multiple change date?

For example I want this to list items that have some modification on previous week

Comment: When you say previous week do you mean Calendar Week (e.g. Sat to Sun) or in last 7 days?

Comment: @Ryan, I mean last 7 days.

Comment: I don't get what you're trying to achieve here - whats that article you ref'd got to do with a modified date?

Comment: Sorry. There was some problem. I removed it.

Comment: Actually, I have a List of tasks with a description column. and specified that every change on that column must be appended to that text fields with change date and username who change it. Then I want to filter the tasks that have any modification in a specific date range. so what is the best solution!

Answer (score 2):

step 1- create a column named ***[TEMP DATE]***

step 2- define a workflow

Note : when we want to track any changes in a SharePoint records , we can start a workflow.

you can define a workflow on changes in all records with SharePoint Designer **to make a copy of modification date  to *[DATE TEMP]***  (that we create in step 1) for keep and hold modification date if happens (check if change occurred on this column then copy to DATE TEMP)

(and then in step 3 filter by this column base on date you want) : for example 10 days before

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010customization/thread/b5fdde13-9b0a-459f-94bf-68636233bf9e/

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/zh/sharepointworkflow/thread/be2ff744-7797-4c8f-befc-c9fd3c133f14

and before define this WF you should define and add Date data type to our custom list.

step 3- create a view : with filtering this Date Column

Answer (score 1):

you can do 3 step with NINTEX component

[image: nintex sample workflow]

step 1- define a workflow

Note : with graphic UI (Nintex designer) you can easily make a workflow steps you want

step 2- define parameter in  named [TEMP DATE]

step 3- create a view : with filtering this Date Column

Answer (score 1):

you can create a Gantt view and set the start and finish of gants for created date and last modified date

and then when you track over the time in Gantt you see any task that between you filter date

Comment: Saber - I am confused why you appear to have 3 answers to this question - whats going on?

Comment: always we have many different ways/solutions for solving a problem. are there uncompleted answers?